# Why does $(window).load() work but not $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, document-ready

I'm working with a rails 3 app, and I want to use a sortable list. I'm working with the method shown [here](http://awesomeful.net/posts/47-sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails). My app uses JQuery, and there's a js file included in my app's layout that calls `$(document).ready()` to set up some visual stuff. That seems to be working fine.

However, when I attempt to call `$(document).ready()` in my view template via `content_for :javascript` to set up the sortable list, that code never fires. I do have the requisite `yield :javascript` call in my layout file, and if I load the page and look at the source everything looks fine. The code never runs, though – i.e. this instance of `$(document).ready()` never fires.

I've just found that if I replace `$(document).ready()` with `$(window).load()` then my js code runs.

So my question is: **Why would `$(document).ready()` fail and `$(window).load()` work?**

### Code

This works:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>

<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
     alert('it works!');
   });
</script>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('it works!');
   });
</script>
<% end %>
```

Here's the Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <!-- Reset Stylesheet -->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "reset" %>
        <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>
        <!-- Invalid Stylesheet -->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "invalid" %>

        <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form", "DD_belatedPNG_0.0.7a", "simpla.jquery.configuration", "facebox", "jquery-ui.min" %>
        <%= yield :javascript %>

    <%= yield(:head) %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()"><div id="body-wrapper">
…
```

Comment: post some example code and i'll give you a cupcake.

Comment: I don't think any one can answer that without some example code or more details.

Comment: OK, sorry. I'll post some code…it's so simple that I'm not sure what to post. Wherever the problem is, I don't think it's in the way that I'm calling these functions or including them in the rails files.

Comment: Can you post your template showing exactly where your `yield` call is?

Comment: Are you using Safari to test? There are some edge cases where `document.ready` doesn't work properly with Safari. Example, if you need to manipulate images. Anyway, it is hard to tell becuase your js is affecting `#text_items` but you don't show that area of your html.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. As I mentioned, the external js file that calls document.ready seems to be working fine. I've tried calling alert() from the above document.ready, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict with the body's `onready=` callback registered. See the jquery docs. You must remove the `<body onload="initialize()">`.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Also a possibility is a resource being loaded very VERY slowly. However the first is more likely.

`.ready` is triggered when resources are loaded. It is possible a resource may be perpetually in a wait state because the server never closed the socket when sending the resource to the browser. Use firebug's network monitor tool to track down if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. However, removing the onload call didn't fix it. ready() still doesn't work!

Comment: @CharlieMezak Upvote if helpful ;) Also update your original issue with this detail for future discussions. However have you used firebug to ensure there is no very slow or stuck resource? Its possible your server does not close the socket, only flushes, and thus .ready never gets triggered. .ready waits for resources to finish loading, and a server does not need to close a socket, so it can cause a perpetual wait.

Answer (score 1):

What about a workaround... Did you know that a `SCRIPT` tag at the end of the `BODY` tag, is executed when everything before is loaded in the `DOM` ?

```
<body>
  <!-- all your HTML here -->
  <script>
    //your starting Javascript code here
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, isn't using $(window).load() a workaround itself? Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: Thanks. I'll bump you, but I'm still hoping for some clarity on the main issue.