# Why does $(document).ready() never fire but $(window).load() will?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, document-ready

I'm working with Rails 3.2.8 and am running jQuery v1.8.2.

The following works:

```
$(window).load(function(){
alert('window load is working');
});
```

But this does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('document ready is working');
});
```

In fact, whenever I switch `$(document).ready()` with `$(window).load()` for any and all jQuery functions I am testing, they are fired. These include accordions, draggable elements...

Here is my **application.html.erb** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body background="<%= image_path(random_bg) %>">
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>

<div id="container">

<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>
</div>
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

The resulting html...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Derp</title>
*bunch of css files*
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/collections.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/global.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/derp.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/test.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
```

I have also gone throw stackoverflow, searched the web neurotically, and tried all the solutions I could find:

- I have tried disabling local jQuery and using Google to host jQuery
- I have tried playing around with the placement of `javascript_include_tag` (moving it above stylesheets, moving it before )
- I tried including `$(document).ready()` inside `$(window).load()`

But `$(document).ready()` still does not fire... There are no problems in console (checked on Chrome, Safari, Firefox)

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022357/why-does-window-load-work-but-not-document-ready), but he never received an answer to his main question.

**Why does jQuery only work when I replace `$(document).ready()` with `$(window).load()`?**

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML? The template isn't too useful here.

Comment: done! Let me know if anything below head is necessary. @Blender

Comment: I'd try removing all of those JS includes except the core jQuery.js and see if it works then. If so, add the others back one at a time until it breaks...

Comment: @nnnnnn this is very weird, but I just removed the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` and replaced it with what it was outputting in HTML. Now all of a sudden, it works! When I put `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` back, it fails again. But the HTML it outputs is identical... Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys,  I solved it by removing some crappy javascript I wrote. It was supposed to be a code that would display labels in browsers that don't support placeholders. Somehow as soon as I deleted the file everything resumed working like normal... Weird how I always spend hours trying to fix a problem and seem to solve them moments after asking a question here!